# Exception in thread "RemoteBlock-temp-file-clean-thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this function;when I uncomment **filter** line; The function is not finished.

```
def create_vouchers(df):
   df = df.withColumnRenamed('time_stamp', 'voucher_date')
   df = df.withColumn('ref_number', F.lpad(df['ref_number'], 10, '0'))
   df = df.withColumn('op_brn_id', F.lpad(df['op_brn_id'], 6, '0'))
   df = df.withColumn('voucher_id',
                           F.concat_ws("", col('trx_date'), col('ref_number'), col('op_brn_id')))
df = df.groupby('voucher_id').agg(F.max(df.voucher_date).alias('voucher_date'),                                                                       F.max(df.approve_date).alias('approve_date'),
                                                                     F.max(df.approver_id).alias('approver_id'),

                                                                     F.max(df.register_date).alias('register_date'),
                                                                     F.max(df.registerer_id).alias('registerer_id'),
                                                                     F.sum('c_amount').alias('sum_c'),
                                                                     F.sum('d_amount').alias('sum_d'))
df = df.withColumn('flag',udf_compare_two_columns(col('sum_c'),col('sum_d')))
df_true = df.filter(df.flag==True)
df_false = df.filter(df.flag==False)
# df = df.select('*').where(col('sum_c')==col('sum_d'))
df_doc = df_true.withColumn('guid', udf_create_objectid())
return df_doc

def compare_two_columns(a, b):
    if a == b:
    result = True
else:
    result = False
return result
```

After running the above code, I receive this error:

```
  Exception in thread "RemoteBlock-temp-file-clean-thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 22/08/27 09:46:49 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread spark-listener-group-appStatus, stopping SparkContext java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception
```

Whould you please guide me what is the problem?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I think the last function took a lot memory. So, when I changed the function to this, there was no error any more.

```
 def create_vouchers(df):
    df = df.withColumnRenamed('timestamp', 'v_date')
    df = df.withColumn('ref_number', F.lpad(df['ref_number'], 10, '0'))
    df = df.withColumn('op_b_id', F.lpad(df['OP_B_ID'], 6, '0'))   
    df = df.groupby('trx_date', 'ref_number', 'op_b_id', 'v_type').agg(
    F.max(df.v_date).alias('v_date'),
    F.max(df.V_GUID).alias('guid'),
    F.max(df.APP_DATE).alias('app_date'),
    F.max(df.APP_ID).alias('app_id'),
    F.max(df.REG_DATE).alias('reg_date'),
    F.max(df.REG_ID).alias('reg_id'),
    F.sum(df.CRD_AMOUNT).alias('sum_crd'),
    F.sum(df.DBT_AMOUNT).alias('sum_dbt'))

    df = df.withColumn('result', col('sum_crd') - col('sum_dbt'))
    df = df.withColumn('v_id',
                   F.concat_ws("", col('trx_date'), col('ref_number'), col('op_b_id'),
                               col('v_type')))
  df_doc = df.filter((col('result') == 0) | (col('v_type') == '1'))
  df_false = df.filter((col('result') != 0) & (col('v_type') == '2'))

  df_error = check_data.filling_df_error(df_false, 'v_id', 'trx', 'InComplete_V')

  return df_error, df_doc
```

I hope it was useful for others.